# Representing children in a B+ Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

I'm building a type of `B+ Tree`, where every node has children which can be a another node, or the actual data of the `B+ Tree`. The actual data in my case is a `char*`.

I was wondering how should I represent the children in the `B+ Tree`. Should I store a `bool` flag saying whether the current node is a leaf?

Here's how one might do it:

```
class Node
{
    size_t key[SIZE];     // Contains the keys of the node
    void* children[SIZE]; // An array of pointers, each one pointing to either another Node or a char*.
};
```

However, how would I check if the children are of type `char*` or `Node*`? I could store a flag, but that would take up extra memory.

**What about with templates?**

```
template <class T>
class Node 
{
    size_t key[SIZE];   // Contains the keys of the node
    T* children[SIZE];
};
```

Would templates work just as well? I read somewhere you can check whether `children` is of type `char*` or `Node*` at compile time, and I don't think there's any extra memory usage.

What would be the best method to this?

Comment: You may have a good case for inheritance here.

Comment: Leaves and internal nodes should be different classes.  Internal nodes would have a `children` array with pointers to a common base class and leaves would have a `T data[SIZE]`  You should allow SIZE to be different in leaves, since the data might be larger or smaller than a pointer.  If you like you can use a common base class with virtual methods.  If you try hard enough, you can do the whole thing without casting.

Comment: @MattTimmermans But wouldn't it work the same if `children` was just simply a `char*`? Also, what do you mean by the data could be larger or smaller than a pointer? `children` is simply an array of pointers which each point to a variable sized character array.